# Type <> does not exist. Where should i define it?

Tags: abap, function-module

I'm trying to write a function module and I stuck with the step below.

[image]

Where can define "Associated type"? I define it in SE11 as Data type->Data Element and it didn't work, then I defined it as Data type->Table type, it didn't work again. Or it already defined somewhere else?

Comment: What does iv_jobname hold? Why do you want to create a new customer type for that? From where will you call this FM?

Comment: iv_jobname is a import type and it need a associated type.
it will hold the data that we send from our app. 
But, actually im not sure what is going on in it.
İm just trying to make my own project based on https:// goo.gl/YVFY73 this project

Comment: İm trying to collect some datas from sm37 with odata and show it somehow.

Comment: Is your data element active? Is your type  specification 'Type' or 'TypeRef' (use Type)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now I figure it out and so close to made it.
Now, I wrote the source code and when I press the check i get an error message. ("The work area "ET_TBT" is not long enough."). ET_TBT is a table type export parameter and its based on the table which i try to get datas. I thing it should be long enough to hold the data anyway. Do you have any idea. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily define table parameters under the tables tab. Why do not use it ? These parameters can be used import and export parameters as well.

Thanks.

Comment: ‘Tables’ parameters are obsolete since years (yes, they still work)

Comment: Old but not obsolete, then. :)